# Копирование текста из консоли Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Надо скопировать текст из консоли Windows, и при возможности внести его в буфер обмена

Comment: Можно по подробнее, что означает "скопировать текст из консоли"?

Comment: Есть некий код который выводит в консоль кучу инфы надо её оттуда достать

Comment: Из консоли windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Прочитать" из консоли нельзя. Можно перенаправить вывод одной команды на вход другой.

```
>PowerShell -Command "dir | python3 file.py"
```

Прочитать `stdin` из скрипта можно так:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    print(line)
```

или так:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)
```

Копировать в буфер обмена можно так:

```
from Tkinter import tk

c = tk().withdraw()
c.clipboard_clear()
c.clipboard_append(line)
c.update()
c.destroy()
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import os

text = 'Ваш текст который нужно скопировать'
cmd = 'echo ' + str(text) + '| clip'

os.system(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл только что модуль pyperclip, он помогает копировать в буфер
то, что выводится в консоль записал в переменную